# Proper way to handle unavoidable warnings

Tags: php

There're many good old procedural functions that can emit warnings due to error conditions that are likely to happen on regular operation, e.g.: `fopen()`, `mail()`, `oci_connect()`...

- The [most obvious workaround](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) is said to be expensive and has the side effect of hiding *everything*:

  ```
  echo @file_get_contents(oops_forgot_dollar);
  ```
- A custom error handler looks overkill:

  ```
  private function warningHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline/*, array $errcontext*/){
      if(error_reporting()===0){
          return false;
      }else{
          throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
      }
  }

  // ....

  try{
      set_error_handler('CSVLoader::warningHandler', E_WARNING);
      $this->fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
      restore_error_handler();

      $this->readData();
  }catch(ErrorException $e){
      restore_error_handler();
      throw new CSVLoaderException("Could not open file: {$e->getMessage()}");
  }
  ```
- Letting the warning pass through is annoying even in a properly configured server:

  - In *developement* they display in the middle of nowhere and can break things
  - In *production* they flood the error log with useless data

What's the recommended practice? How do PHP gurus handle it?

Comment: Usually by checking that the correct conditions are set before making the function calls, i.e. with `file_get_contents`, do an `is_readable` call before hand, which doesn't throw an error but will give you an insight into whether `file_get_contents` is going to error

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ - I'm not really convinced. How can you know in advance whether a database server will accept connections? Even if you get stubborn and simulate one with `fsockopen()` you'll need *more* previous checks in case `fsockopen()` also triggers a warning. That approach also means opting out of facilities like `file_get_contents()`: any code to read files will require lots of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

The error_log is not *useless data*

I find it's usually easy enough to keep on top of if there's an hourly cron job that emails the contents of the error_log file to someone .....

Soon you'll have added in the appropriate checks to the code base and the problems sorted.

Comment: I appreciate you took the time to compose an answer but I'm not sure you actually understood my question. Imagine you maintain a library to send email. Your library throws a nice `FooMailer\TransportException` when the outgoing SMTP connection fails. What sense does it make to trigger (and log!) an additional non-catchable `E_WARNING`? Wouldn't end users find more reasonable to just tag the message as not send in their newsletter database?

Comment: End users will never find error_log or similar messages of much help - they need a more helpful message ("Sorry, something really bad happened", "You didn't fill all the form fields in correctly). 

How you detect in your that something's gone wrong is up to you. Exceptions have their place as does checking return values or whatever.

Obviously when designing your app/system you know somethings are likely to fail (sending a newsletter to lots of addresses, and can be retried at a later date) while other things are Exceptional events - (e.g. DB server is dead)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a quick dirty slanted unscientific survey among some popular PHP frameworks and popular Packagist packages and found this:

- Error suppression operator is reasonably popular (CodeIgniter, Nette, Swift Mailer, Yii...).
- Quite other projects use `set_error_handler()` to throw `ErrorException` or some other exception (Zend, Symfony, Laravel, PHPUnit, Psy...). Most simply use a project-wide error handler, a few (PHPMailer) wrap specific operations in set/restore calls.
- Some other projects apparently just don't care (PHPExcel).

I'd say that:

- If you already have a custom error handler it's probably better to leverage it.
- Otherwise, error control operator can be just fine (but it's probably a good idea to remove it temporarily while you develop that piece of code). The alleged bad performance [doesn't seem to be a big deal](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2014/09/correct-use-of-phps-at-operator-with-speed-benchmark/) anyway*, esp. if you are doing a "slow" operation like opening a database connection, socket or file.
- As debate, it's probably in the same area than tabs vs spaces.

*(*) I found endless benchmarks that compare `@` versus `isset()` and determine that `@` is very slow. What really happens is that `isset()` is very fast—actually [much faster that not using either](https://eval.in/399662).*

---

Last but not least, since performance matters, I'll share my first home-brew benchmark—once more a quick and dirty one, without a proper benchmarking framework. Please note I'm only testing so far the **worst scenario** (all function calls generate a warning):

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', false);
ini_set('log_errors', false);


define('ITERATIONS', 10000);


function warning_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline/*, array $errcontext*/){
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}


echo sprintf('Running %s iterations on PHP/%s...' . PHP_EOL, number_format(ITERATIONS), phpversion());


$t0 = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<ITERATIONS; $i++){
    fopen("FooA $i", 'r');
}
echo sprintf('Raw:                         % 6.3fs' . PHP_EOL, microtime(true) - $t0);


$t0 = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<ITERATIONS; $i++){
    @fopen("FooB $i", 'r');
}
echo sprintf('@:                           % 6.3fs' . PHP_EOL, microtime(true) - $t0);


$t0 = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<ITERATIONS; $i++){
    set_error_handler('warning_handler', E_WARNING);
    try{
        fopen("FooC $i", 'r');
        restore_error_handler();
    }catch(ErrorException $e){
        restore_error_handler();
    }
}
echo sprintf('Local set_error_handler():   % 6.3fs' . PHP_EOL, microtime(true) - $t0);


$t0 = microtime(true);
set_error_handler('warning_handler', E_WARNING);
for($i=0; $i<ITERATIONS; $i++){
    try{
        fopen("FooD $i", 'r');
    }catch(ErrorException $e){
    }
}
restore_error_handler();
echo sprintf('General set_error_handler(): % 6.3fs' . PHP_EOL, microtime(true) - $t0);
```

Results on my Windows 7 box (x86 PHP builds):

```
Running 10,000 iterations on PHP/5.3.28...
Raw:                          1.388s
@:                            1.232s
Local set_error_handler():    1.638s
General set_error_handler():  1.497s
```

```
Running 10,000 iterations on PHP/5.4.24...
Raw:                          1.170s
@:                            1.185s
Local set_error_handler():    1.357s
General set_error_handler():  1.326s
```

```
Running 10,000 iterations on PHP/5.5.22...
Raw:                          1.185s
@:                            1.341s
Local set_error_handler():    4.960s
General set_error_handler():  4.570s
```

```
Running 10,000 iterations on PHP/5.6.10...
Raw:                          1.139s
@:                            1.139s
Local set_error_handler():    1.263s
General set_error_handler():  1.232s
```

```
Running 10,000 iterations on PHP/7.0.0beta1...
Raw:                          1.232s
@:                            1.279s
Local set_error_handler():    1.669s
General set_error_handler():  1.669s
```